# Can I use a PoE+ hat (802.3at) on raspberry pi with a PoE (802.3af) switch

Tags: pi-4, poe

I've wanted to setup some rpi4 with PoE hats and a PoE switch.

I've seen in local markets that both old PoE hats and PoE+ hats have the same price.

I've also seen that the old PoE hats have no stock available in these shops.

Now, since there is no difference in price, and stock for the old ones is gone, it's "no brainer" to buy the new model (PoE+) for the PIs.

BUT, there is a huge difference in price for the switches (PoE vs PoE+).

Can I use the new hats (PoE+) with a switch that supports "only" PoE? I'm aware that I won't get the full wattage a PoE+ offers (and I don't need it), but since the old PoE hats are hard to find (and I will have to wait a lot), I'm simply thinking of getting the new ones.

So can the new PoE+ (802.3at) hat for RPi "recognize" the PoE (802.3af) input and work with it?

Comment: according to [this official raspberry pi documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/announcing-the-raspberry-pi-poe-hat/) `Standards supported 802.3af, 802.3at`

Comment: Well, it was a simple as looking at the official documentation (even though I tried google it and missed it). Thanks a lot. If you want post the answer so I can accept it as the solution.